# disable usercontrol on the load of master page

Tags: asp.net

I am using master page on some pages. And that master page is loading the user control. So I want to disable or enable user control on some page load which has master page.

---

Is there anyway can I disable User control on master page Page_load()

---

```
<div class="ucTabCtrl" >
    <uc1:TLTabControl ID="ctrlname" runat="server" Visible="False" />
</div>

Master Page_load()
{
 // checking some condition if true
 ctrlname.visible = true;
}
```

but the problem is I'm not able to get the instance of user ctrl, in short ctrlname is null all the time.

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear.  You need to elaborate and describe your page setup and explain which pages you want the control disabled on.  Give a simplified code example if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kinda hard to understand, but i think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page is WebForm1 || Page is WebForm2)
        {
            webUserControl11.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could implement an interface on the pages that indicates this behavior. Something along the lines:

```
public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISpecialPage specialPage = Page as ISpecialPage;

        if (specialPage != null && specialPage.ShouldDisableUserControl)
            webUserControl11.Visible = false;
    }
}

public interface ISpecialPage
{
    bool ShouldDisableUserControl { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to disable it on the child page?  You could do something like this in the Page_Load() method:

```
if (null != this.Master)
{
    userControl.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway can I disable User control on master page Page_load()

Comment: You'd probably have to use FindControl() from the context of the content placeholder and look for a particular user control.

Comment: There is no Enabled property for usercontrols on a host page.

Answer (score 0):

The user control is not declared as a local variable in the MasterPage. You need to use the FindControl() function to get a reference to the control.

Here's a working example:

```
Dim userControl As WebControl = ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("someControl")
If userControl IsNot Nothing Then
   CType(userControl, WebControl).Enabled = False
End If
```